# UIViewController subviews exist but I see black screen

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I have 2 view controllers, the first is a storyboard (this is root) and the second with is nibless. When I press a button in the root view controller it should call the second controller.

Here the code for my second view controller:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        UILabel *sampleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0,0,100,100)];
        UIImageView * basketItem = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"B.jpg"]];
        [self.view addSubview:sampleLabel];
        [self.view addSubview:basketItem];
        NSLog(@"%@",self.view.subviews);
        sampleLabel.text = @"Main Menu";
    }
    return self;
}
```

self.view.sebviews query shows that 2 objects  label and imageView objects exists, but in fact I see black screen only.

Here is transition method

```
- (void)transitionToViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController
  withOptions:(UIViewAnimationOptions)options
{
      aViewController.view.frame = self.containerView.bounds;
      [UIView transitionWithView:self.containerView
                  duration:0.65f
                   options:options
                animations:^{
                    [self.viewController.view removeFromSuperview];
                    [self.containerView addSubview:aViewController.view];
                }
                completion:^(BOOL finished){
                    self.viewController = aViewController;
                }];    
}
```

Comment: Are you using init as @sqreept suggested?

Comment: What about `[myClassInstance transitionToViewController:vc withOptions:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight];`? Please, edit your question and insert other details as possible. Obviously, insert the main ones.

Comment: As far I know I don't know a class in UI that uses this **transitionToViewController** method. Do you use any external class?

Comment: Please add your edit in your question. **NOT** in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Move the code in `viewDidLoad`. Here you are sure the view has been loaded into memory and hence can be further customized.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UILabel *sampleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0,100,100,100)];
    UIImageView * basketItem = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"B.jpg"]];
    [self.view addSubview:sampleLabel];
    [self.view addSubview:basketItem];
    NSLog(@"%@",self.view.subviews);
    sampleLabel.text = @"Main Menu";    
}
```

**If you are not using ARC, pay attention to memory leaks.**

**Note**

I really suggest to read Apple doc for this. You should understand how things work. Hope that helps.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ViewLoadingandUnloading/ViewLoadingandUnloading.html

**Edit**

I don't know what the problem could be. To make it work, try to override `loadView` (in `MenuViewController`) method like the following:

```
- (void)loadView
{
    CGRect applicationFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
    UIView *contentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:applicationFrame];
    contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]; // red color only for debug purposes
    self.view = contentView;
}
```

Leave the `viewDidLoad` method as I wrote and see what happens.

When you create the view controller use only `init` method.

```
MenuViewController *vc = [[MenuViewController alloc] init];
```

Comment: @GeorgeOh Provide some other details

Comment: This methods are declared in VC inherited class, which is my second VC, and was called from root VC m file in this way

Comment: @GeorgeOh Could you provide the code used for creating that controller?

Comment: MenuViewController *vc = [[MenuViewController alloc] initWithNibName: nil bundle:nil ] ;
    
    //Use class method
    [myClassInstance transitionToViewController:vc withOptions:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight];

Comment: Are you using init as @sqreept suggested?

Comment: Yes I just changed                                     MenuViewController *vc = [[MenuViewController alloc] initWithNibName: nil bundle:nil ] ; to                                MenuViewController *vc = [[MenuViewController alloc] init] ;

Comment: You'll have to provide more code. Eventually a full simplified project that reproduces the issue.

Comment: flexaddicted , I'm really sorry to say that the result is black screen :( I'm really confused with this black screen!

Comment: Added, please see it above.

Answer (score 1):

Your `UILabel`'s `frame` has `size.width=0`:

```
CGRectMake(0,100,0,100)
```

and if `B.jpg` is not added to the project you `UIImageView` will also be empty.

Also, if second `UIViewController` doesn't have a XIB, initialize it using the `- (id)init` method instead of `- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil`.

Comment: Indeed :) I've fixed it but problem still exists.

Comment: Also code that adds subviews should reside in `viewDidLoad` because `self.view` is nil in the `init` method.

Comment: Originally, "subview adding" was exist in both initWithNibName and viewDidLoad methods, but result is same.

Comment: Look in the XIB for alpha setting on the view in XIB is 0 or hidden flag set to YES.

Comment: Second viewcontroller doesn't use xib. Is it necessary?

Comment: I just want to create VC with coding only .

Comment: Ok, I've changed it to init, but still same result.